# Deep nested array of objects not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a fairly nested array which is formed from retrieving data from Firebase, modifying it and passing it down as props. The structure of the array is 
[image]

Every array(2) has values pretty much in the same format. I'm trying to render the 2 months = 1, mild = 3, etc. datapoints from each 'array(2)'[0] object as well as the datapoints from 'array(2)' [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGXNt.png) such as RWJ = 2.5, (the 0 object right above it is the same exact format of data). I tried to first render the key 'RWJ' using the following 
[image]

When I try to execute this, nothing renders. However, when I call a simple function which logs 'thirdData' to the console, it prints out exactly what I'm looking for.

[image]
[image]

```
thirdData = (value) => {
  console.log(value)
}
```

Pretty lost as too whats going on here, so any help would be appreciated. Also, when I use a much simpler array of the modified Firebase data, it renders, so I'm pretty sure there's no problem with the props being passed down after the component renders.

Comment: You're missing `return` before `<div>`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are not returning anything from inside the `innermost` map function.

```
return Object.keys(secondData).map((thirdData, i) => {
     return <div key={i}>
           {this.thirdData(thirdData)}
     </div>
}
```

P.S. Make sure you assign unique keys to iterator as well

One thing to note here is the difference between `() => {}` and `() => (...)`, in the second case whatever you write is within `(...)` is returned explicitly whereas in the first case its a block from which you need to `return the content`

so you could have simply written

```
return Object.keys(secondData).map((thirdData, i) => (
     return <div key={i}>
           {this.thirdData(thirdData)}
     </div>
)
```