# ES6 array map doesn't return anything: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array and i have a simple string value. I want to mapping my array because i'm try to find my string value.

I have a code like this, but map function doesn't return anything :/

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      questionAnswer: 'is that possible',
      question: ['is', 'possible', 'that']
    }  
  }

  renderKeywords() {
    this.state.question.map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <span>{item}</span>
      );
    }); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>blabla</div>
        {this.renderKeywords()}  
      </div>
   );
 }
}
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep nested array of objects not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072608/deep-nested-array-of-objects-not-rendering)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything from `renderKeywords` method, you are returning from map body only. If you don't return anything from function then by default it will return `undefined`, you need to return the result of map (array of elements).

Like this:

```
renderKeywords() {
    return this.state.question.map((item, key) => {   //here
        return (
            <span key={key}> {item} </span>
        );
    }); 
}
```

In short you can write it like this:

```
renderKeywords() {
   return this.state.question.map((item, key) => <span key={key}> {item} </span> ); 
}
```

**Suggestion:**

Assign unique **[key](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)** to each element.

Check this answer for more details about key: [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

you should return the map function itself, and you can achieve it with es6 single line arrow functions too

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      questionAnswer: 'is that possible',
      question: ['is', 'possible', 'that']
    }  
  }

  renderKeywords() {
    return this.state.question.map((item, i) =><span key={i}>{item}
   </span>}); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>blabla</div>
        {this.renderKeywords()}  
      </div>
   );
 }
}
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't bring anything new to the question and is basically just repeating already accepted answer...

Comment: i have updated the es6 arrow function which is the actual implementation of it when you are directly returning something from it. @MarekTakac