# Unable to get JSX to render from a condition within map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There are quite a few questions and answers on this topic out there already, but I don't seem to get my JSX to render properly from a condtion within a map() function.

The function I am calling from my render() function looks like this:

```
renderAudiobookChoice(audioBookChoice) {
  if (audioBookChoice === "all") {
    return this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => (
      <AudiobookDetail key={audiobook.id} audiobook={audiobook} />
    ));
  }

  if (audioBookChoice === "poetry") {
    this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => {
      return audiobook.text_type === 2 ? (
        <AudiobookDetail key={audiobook.id} audiobook={audiobook} />
      ) : null;
    });
  }
}
```

So if my audioBookChoice = 'all', the AudiobookDetails are rendered properly.
But if I audioBookChoice = 'poetry', it does not render anything to the screen anymore.

My linter gives me the follwoing warning: "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function. (array-callback-return)".
This is confusing me, as I am under the impression that I should be returning something following my terniary operator.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [map doesn't return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670326/es6-array-map-doesnt-return-anything-reactjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the the return in the `poetry` section:

```
if (audioBookChoice === 'poetry') {
    return (
      this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => {
        return audiobook.text_type === 2 ?
            <AudiobookDetail 
                key={audiobook.id} audiobook={audiobook} 
            />

        : 
            null;
        });
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick help!

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the result inside of your second if statement.

```
if (audioBookChoice === "poetry") {
  return this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => {
    return audiobook.text_type === 2 ? (
      <AudiobookDetail key={audiobook.id} audiobook={audiobook} />
    ) : null;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not returning the map of the array anymore.

use this:

```
if (audioBookChoice === "poetry") {
  return this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => {
    return audiobook.text_type === 2 ? (
      <AudiobookDetail key={audiobook.id} audiobook={audiobook} />
    ) : null;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing return statement,change to

```
 if (audioBookChoice === "poetry") {
    return this.state.audiobooks.map(audiobook => {
      return audiobook.text_type === 2 ? (
        <AudiobookDetail key={audiobook.id} audiobook={audiobook} />
      ) : null;
    });
  }
}
```