# render state in map function and add some style react js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i want to add some style to state with map function and finally add items in table i use this code

```
    columnClassNameFormat(fieldValue ) {
    const Event =this.state.Event;
    console.log(Event);

    this.state.Event.events.map(function (item) {
        if (item.event_type === 'A') {

         <span class="label label-danger">{fieldValue}</span>
        }
        else if (item.event_type === 'W') {
        <span class="label label-warning">{fieldValue}</span>
        }
        else if (item.event_type === 'I') {
            <span class="label label-info">{fieldValue}</span>
        } else {
          <span class="label label-info">{fieldValue}</span>
        }
    }).bind(this)


 }
```

and after that i show items in table like that

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.Event}  exportCSV title='Infravision-Report' pagination search>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='event_title' isKey={ true }>Discription</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='time' dataSort={ true }>Date time</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='event_status' columnClassName={this.columnClassNameFormat } >status</TableHeaderColumn>


                    </BootstrapTable>
```

but its not work and style not add to items

Comment: Put `return` statement .... `return this.state.Event.events.map(...)`

Comment: And..`return (<span> ....</span>)` .... for all span(s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep-nested-array-of-objects-not-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072608/deep-nested-array-of-objects-not-rendering/45072666#45072666)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map function should have return statements like,

```
this.state.Event.events.map(function (item) {
        if (item.event_type === 'A') {

         return <span class="label label-danger">{fieldValue}</span>
        }
        else if (item.event_type === 'W') {
        return <span class="label label-warning">{fieldValue}</span>
        }
        else if (item.event_type === 'I') {
           return  <span class="label label-info">{fieldValue}</span>
        } else {
         return  <span class="label label-info">{fieldValue}</span>
        }
    }) .bind(this)
```

Comment: I havent added the .bind from your question. Edited my answer now. please try the latest

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful